# multiple thread website crawling using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, web-crawler

Here's my code ([link](http://pastebin.com/umP9nZ4P)):

```
import urllib, urllib2, re
import threading, Queue

somewebsite = 'xxx' 

urls5 = []
for i in range(50001, 60000):
    url = somewebsite + str(i)
    urls5.append(url)

class MultiUrl(threading.Thread):  
    def __init__(self, queue):  
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)  
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):  
        while True:  
            url = self.queue.get()
            try:  
                Go(url)
            except:  
                continue  
            self.queue.task_done()


def main():
    queue = Queue.Queue()
    for i in range(16):  
        t = MultiUrl(queue)  
        t.setDaemon(True)   
        t.start() 

    for url in urls5:
        queue.put(url) 
    queue.join()

def Go(url):
    try:
        print "Now grabbing...", url
        getArticle(url)
        if (OriginalContentList != []):
            writeContent()
    except:
        pass

def getArticle(url):
    global content, Content
    i = re.findall('\d+', url)[0]
    ArticleID = str(i)
    try:
        content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        Content = urllib.unquote(content)
    except:
        OriginalContentList = []
        pass

def writeContent():
    # Origin Content
    try:
        filename = ArticleID + '.txt'
        file_out = open(filename, 'w')
        file_out.write(Content)
        file_out.write('\n')
        file_out.close()
    except:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Single-thread crawling can't deal with that much articles (>=200000), so I Google(d) and chose thread and queue.

Problem is that: program can't write content to correspond file. For example, it may write content of No.55555 into 55666.txt .

Comment if my description isn't accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simple way to implement multi-threading, but I forgot where it came from..

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(5)
results = pool.map(function_name, url_list)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The shortage is that, it can't handle errors, so you should consider how to properly write that function. [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) is a great tool.

Also more convenient libs for accessing web content: [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

and content storage: [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/)

Comment: If you don't use `results`, you'd better to use following: `for _ in pool.imap_unordered(function_name, url_list): pass`

Comment: @falsetru , thank you. Would you please kindly explain your advice? :)

Comment: `map` will not return until all tasks to be finished. And the order of the list item should be ordered. If that is not required, you can use `imap_unordered` instead; which return immediately; iterating will yield any finished tasks' return values in any order.

Comment: @falsetru I tried with print(taskurl), sometimes it would print one url twice.....

Comment: Did you check the original list contians duplication? `len(url_list) == len(set(url_list))`

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are shared by multiple threads.
One thread can overwrite a variable while other thread is reading it.

Avoid using global variable if possible.

Comment: okay okay .. i combined my function together and added some "try" and "except" then the program works fine.. thank you !